# How the base controller gets updated data when child controller action method update the value

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

CurrentSession in the BaseController is always empty even after user logon and updated CurrentSession values inside Logon action method under the AccountController. Because, BaseController constructor is called before hitting LogonAction method from child controller. How to solve this?

```
  public class BaseController : Controller
  {
    public BaseController()
    {
        ViewData["Base_General"] = JSONRequestGeneral();

     }

   private static string JSONRequestGeneral()
    {
        MySession mysession = SessionHelper.CurrentSession;

        if (mysession != null)
        {
              GeneralModel generalModel = new GeneralModel();
                 //add model values here
                generalModel.user = submitterModel;

        }
        return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(generalModel);
    }
```

}

```
  public class AccountController : BaseController
  {
     public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model)
    {
               //create submitter here
               MySession current = new MySession();
                    current.SubmitterId = ExistingSubmitter.Id;
                    
                    current.SubmitterName = ExistingSubmitter.Name;

                    current.SubmitterEmail = ExistingSubmitter.Email;
                   
                    SessionHelper.CurrentSession = current;

                  return Redirect(currentURL);
   }
```

}

Comment: What is `SessionHelper.CurrentSession`?

Comment: `ViewData["Base_General"] = JSONRequestGeneral();` - why is this called from the constructor? Nothing related to the processing of a request should be in the constructor.